# Raspberry cross-compiling and sqlite3

Tags: c++, sqlite, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling

I am just working on some c++ program for Raspberry Pi, and i have to use cross-compiling, with several libraries from other projects too. Using targets to make a cross-compiled program which can run os Raspberry. But i also need some database too. Was thinking to work with SQLite, but is it possible to invoke sqlite3 compiler plus the cross-compiling same time? Or how can compile a program which uses make files/target plus sqlite too?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to compile SQLLite just once, if you don't want to have trouble to cross compile it on your development machine why don't you just compile it once directly on Raspberry?

Comment: You can try [biicode](http://docs.biicode.com/en/latest/hardware/rpi/configuration.html), it will automatically integrate [sqlite](https://www.biicode.com/sqlite/blocks/sqlite/sqlite/branches/master) and cross compile it for you

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

had to add the sqlite library to compiler as a variable. yes i was fighitng with it somewhile.
I ve did the following: added =lsqlite to the end of my g++ command:

```
g++ -L "../../partialLibrary" -o "Tutorial" $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS) $(LIBS) -lsqlite3
```

so now it uses the sqlite library too when compiling

Thanks for the helps anyways!